# Advanced quantum field theory by David Tong

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, specific-reference

I am looking for the advanced quantum field theory PDF by David Tong, possibly called symmetries and particle physics. I have his quantum field theory PDF and am looking for his PDF on advanced quantum field theory, although I don't know what the title is.

Comment: A Google search find all David Tong's lectures at: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/teaching.html You probably want the lectures on "Gauge theory" as that is the most advanced one there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to ask for links for copyrighted material.

Comment: The material is not copyrighted. Tong makes his notes free for everyone.

Comment: ^ OP does say "book" not lecture notes, may be referring to something else which could be copyrighted.

Comment: Revised to say PDF instead of book.

Comment: You may be thinking of David *Skinner*'s Advanced Quantum Field Theory lecture notes.